# Expanding parent container from absolute child that gets it's size from parent

Tags: css, responsive-design, parent-child, multiple-columns, fluid-layout

I am working on my first drupal site and although I have good web programming skillz (css, jscript, php) I'm trying to follow drupal markup using their templates as completely as possible.

My problem is a 3 column responsive site which I don't have much experience with. My left and right columns (13% + 1% margin) are divs that visually represent colored stripes that extend down the length of the parent container and the center div (72%) is where the content goes. problem is I decided to let the parent container control the size of the child divs by setting the children to absolute and using margins to stretch the children to the dimensions of the parent. **(top:x;left:x;bottom:x;right:x;)** - to stretch the vertical I use **parent_container:after** and **display:block;padding-top:xx%;**

the columns are vertically split by a menu wrapper and while the top container is fine with a set height (**padding-top:xx%**), the bottom container needs to expand as the content dictates.

Question: how can I make the child resize the parent based on the child's content if the children are getting their size from the parent? thanks!

```
#main-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

#main-wrapper:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    padding-top:46%;
}

#main-wrapper-left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:1%;bottom:0;right:86%;
    background:#CC0000; 
}

#main-wrapper-left img {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
}

#main-wrapper-left a{
    display:block;
}

#main-wrapper-right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:86%;bottom:0;right:1%;
    background:#0600ff;
}

#main-wrapper-center{   
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:14%;bottom:0;right:14%;
    background: #ffffff;
}

<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="main-wrapper-left"> images and links go here </div>
    <div id="main-wrapper-center"> header slideshow goes here </div>
    <div id="main-wrapper-right"> images and links go here </div>
</div>

<div> menu </div> // this is where the menu div goes which splits the page page in two

<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="main-wrapper-left"> advertisements </div>
    <div id="main-wrapper-center"> main content goes here </div>
    <div id="main-wrapper-right"> advertisements </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never use `position: absolute` for major parts of your layout. It's a world of pain, and just not worth it. There are many options for columns, like `float`, `display: inline-block` or `display: table-cell`, so no need for positioning at all. :-) You've also made a mistake there by using an ID twice. If you need to repeat an element, use a class instead.

Comment: if I'm going to rewrite then I think I'd like to use 3 divs with display: inline-block ... how can I set their height fluidly?

Comment: Their heights will be fluid by default, whether you use `float` or `inline-block` or `display: table`. It's just `position: absolute` that jumps out of the flow of the document and is hard to manage.

Comment: I guess what I meant to say was how can I set their height to 100% of the parent container without losing fluidity? not every div is stuffed with enough content to get them to stretch to the total height I need them to be.

Comment: Height:100% is tricky, because it only works if the parent has a set height, which you normally don't want. I'd say your best option is to use display: table on the parent and display: table-cell on the columns, as that will at least keep all the columns the same height.

Comment: I recoded the site for inline-blocks instead and it almost works fine. have created another question to solve my sticking point on a height:(percentage) problem I'm having. content won't expand the parent container if I specify a height on the wrapper div or child divs won't expand to 100% parent height if I remove height:xx% restriction on the wrapper. :/